# "Error loading target specification" when building a WebAssembly module with Cargo

Tags: rust, webassembly

I've constructed a simple Rust app as follows:

```
cargo new hello_world --bin
```

I can compile to WebAssembly using the Rust compiler as follows:

```
rustc +nightly --target wasm32-unknown-unknown -O src/main.rs
```

I'd like to use Cargo to manage external dependencies, but when I build for the same target using `cargo`:

```
cargo build --release --target wasm32-unknown-unknown
```

It fails as follows:

```
$ cargo build --release --target wasm32-unknown-unknown
error: failed to run `rustc` to learn about target-specific information

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `rustc - --crate-name ___ --print=file-names --target wasm32-unknown-unknown --crate-type bin --crate-type rlib` (exit code: 101)
--- stderr
error: Error loading target specification: Could not find specification for target "wasm32-unknown-unknown"
  |
  = help: Use `--print target-list` for a list of built-in targets
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the `wasm32-unknown-unknown` target has only recently been added to Rust, it's only available in the nightly toolchain. You have to specify that you wish to use the nightly toolchain:

```
cargo +nightly build --release --target wasm32-unknown-unknown
#     ^^^^^^^^
```

You were already doing this when calling `rustc` directly:

```
rustc +nightly --target wasm32-unknown-unknown -O src/main.rs
#     ^^^^^^^^
```

---

It's probably easier if you:

1. Use a toolchain *override* in your project directory:

   ```
   $ rustup override set nightly
   ```
2. Set a default target in your project's `.cargo/config`:

   ```
   [build]
   target = "wasm32-unknown-unknown"
   ```

Then you can just `cargo build --release`. (It's recommended to avoid debug mode for now).