# Code coverage in Rust - "failed to run `rustc` to learn about target-specific information"

Tags: rust, code-coverage

I am trying to get code coverage for my project in Rust. I am following the instructions provided here: https://marco-c.github.io/2020/11/24/rust-source-based-code-coverage.html

Based on that (and from https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch01-03-hello-cargo.html), I followed the steps:

```
cd projects                      // this could be really anything. Just meant to say I am in a clean directory.
cargo new hello_world --bin      // creates a new module with hello world
export RUSTFLAGS="-Zinstrument-coverage"
cargo build
```

Results in following error:

```
error: failed to run `rustc` to learn about target-specific information

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `rustc - --crate-name ___ --print=file-names -Zinstrument-coverage --crate-type bin --crate-type rlib --crate-type dylib --crate-type cdylib --crate-type staticlib --crate-type proc-macro --print=sysroot --print=cfg` (exit status: 1)
  --- stderr
  error: the option `Z` is only accepted on the nightly compiler
```

I followed the post: ["Error loading target specification" when building a WebAssembly module with Cargo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47743705/error-loading-target-specification-when-building-a-webassembly-module-with-car) which has a similar error. But I did not run any `rustc` command before. So I am not sure if the suggestion there is valid.

My end goal is to not debug this specific error but just try to find a workable way to get code coverage for the project from the command line. So, if I can debug this issue, that's great or if there is something else which I should follow, please point me to it.

Also, I use Intellij - on which I can get code coverage. But I would like to learn that using a command-line approach.

Thanks!

Comment: Wild guess, have you gotten the toolchain with `rustup component add llvm-tools-preview`?

Comment: @CtrlAltF2 - yes. `rustup component add llvm-tools-preview
info: component 'llvm-tools-preview' for target 'x86_64-apple-darwin' is up to date`

Comment: Oh, look at the error message. "The option Z is only accepted on the nightly compiler." You need to switch to the nightly toolchain.

Comment: Ok. Perhaps a dumb follow-up question - how do I do that?

Comment: nvm: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48675235/error-the-option-z-is-only-accepted-on-the-nightly-compiler/48675452 is helpful. Let me give it a shot and get back!

Comment: So, I am able to get the issue of getting the cargo build to go with the nightly compiler. But I am not able to still completely get the code coverage for the project.